# Downloads from browsers are broken, downloads using wget or curl are not

Tags: safari, command-line, google-chrome, data-transfer, firefox

I restored my mac after getting it back from Apple. It had a busted logic board.
After getting it back any download from any browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc) is flagged by macOS as damaged and should be deleted.
I have disabled Gatekeeper and still get the same issue.
Any file downloaded via wget or a similar CLI utility work just fine.
Does anyone have any idea about what is going on here?

[image]

Comment: Are you thinking Safari isn’t to be trusted and looking for a triage step like new user account, test the ultimate download - an erase / reinstall from Internet Recovery?

Comment: What model of **Mac**? What version of **macOS**? Is the version of **macOS** up to date with its security updates? Have you rebooted and tried downloading the _file_ again? Have you check the _extended attributes_ on the _file_ and tried removing its `com.apple.quarantine` _extended attribute_ using `xattr` from **Terminal**?

Comment: Hi Thomas, welcome to Ask Different. You write "any download (...) is flagged by macOS as damaged and should be deleted", is this a message that macOS displays after download? If that's the case, could you add a screenshot of such a message? What kind of files are you downloading (PDFs, video or music files, zipped files...)?

Comment: I've tried with .dmg, .jpg and .zip so far. 
The message is shown when I try to open the file from the Downloads folder. I am attaching a screenshot to the original post now.

Comment: @user3439894 It is a Late 2017 MBP. Restored to Catalina. 
The file is flagged with com.apple.quarantine. 
I have attempted to restart the machine, to no avail.

Comment: If in **Terminal** you use e.g., `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/filename` and it removes that _extended attribute_, will the downloaded _file_ open okay then? What version of **macOS Catalina** are you running?

Comment: Yes. Removing the xattr allows me to open a file. I am on 10.15.5.